# Symfony: User login without username (interface restrictions)?

Tags: security, symfony, authentication, authorization, bundle

I'd like to build my custom login-bundle in symfony 2.5. I don't want to use the FOSUserBundle because my login-bundle will work with other logic. My logic:

1. A user can have multiple emails, but only on primary emails. The emails will be listed in another entity (UserEmail). A foreign key will refer to the id of the primary-email
2. A user must **not have a username** or something else to login, he can just use a email-adress of those who are refering to his account (in UserEmail)
3. Another entity called UserRole will have a foreign key to the UserEntity with his role.

I already created all my entities: User, UserEmail and UserRole. So I'm trying to realize my SecurityController. But unfortunately there are some limitations I found in the documentation:

> In order to use an instance of the AcmeUserBundle:User class in the
> Symfony security layer, the entity class must implement the
> UserInterface. This interface forces the class to implement the five
> following methods
>
> 1. `getRoles()`
> 2. `getPassword()`
> 3. `getSalt()`
> 4. `getUsername()`
> 5. `eraseCredential()`

So my login will not include point 4 `getUsername()` because the user will not have a username.

**How can I realize my user login without a username?**

Comment: Can't you use the email as username?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. it's totally confusing to name it username in the sourcecode, but mean a email.

Comment: But you said you don't have username.

Comment: Yes, I don't have a username and I don't want to name my user-email "username"

Comment: You don't have to rename it, just create it like an alias, where getUserName() will return the email address.

Comment: Will this have no other effect? I mean where will getUsername() be used?

Comment: Why not using an ID as the user username? It provides more logic in your concept: an ID is unique, will never change during the time unless you change it manually. You can display a primary email address or a list of addresses to your user when you need it. If you want to recognize your user by any unique property, this is what ID should be used to (just this as unique identifiers work in database world - this is almost the same use case).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you implement the getUsername() method to return the user's id? This way you can use the UserInterface.

```
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->getId();
}
```

I have the same problem as you. All my User just need one email and password to connect, I don't use any username. But I had to implement all user-related interfaces to handle a Symfony connection and I used the above solution.

It is misleading, of course, in my code I have for instance

```
public function loadByUsername($username)
{
    findBy(array('email' => $username));
    ....
}
```

But I think this is the only solution right now.

Comment: Where will symfony use the getUsername()-method? Maybe this will make troubles

Comment: It disgusts me to use something that was not made for it. But if there is no other way, I have to accept it. It will make my code hard to understand, but ok.

Comment: I don't know any other way, but I might be wrong. Symfony will use the getUsername method to display to current logged in user in the profiler, for instance. But I know that when I do $this->getUser() in my controllers, I get the right user.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Emails entity then it must be related to User Entity
the relation is one to many from User Side, so you can must have a field in User entity that hold the array of Email entity
if getUsername() function you can loop through all email and return any one of them that you want

```
    function getUserName(){
    // $Email is an array it will hold the array of email entity 
    // as it is in one to many relationship with User Entity

    foreach($Emails as $email){ // loop through each email
    if($email->your_flag_to_identify_primery_username==true){
    return $email->email_address; // return that match according to flag set by you

    }
```

further you have to write custom authentication mechanism this   [link](http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/symfony2-login-username-e-mail/) will be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

getUsername() not always using `username` as fieldname.
Maybe you can take this as example, This is showing how to use `email` as field name :

```
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_ADMIN');
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt,
    ));
}

public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
}
```

You can also using array as your username, let me know if you using array as collection of your email.

**NOTE :** You can still using getEmail() to return email in your entity. You can create more than one different function name to return same field in your entity. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using an ID as the user username? It provides more logic in your concept: an ID is unique, will never change during the time unless you change it manually. You can display a primary email address or a list of addresses to your user when you need it. If you want to recognize your user by any unique property, this is what ID should be used to (just this as unique identifiers work in database world - this is almost the same use case).

An example of entity getter:

```
class User {
    ...

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    ...
}
```